# Node.js: Image src causes error, reruns database statement and doesnt show alt text

Tags: node.js, database, image, express, sequelize.js

Me and my friend are trying to build a simple ecommerce shop with node, ejs, sequelize but I noticed something very interesting.
If I try to add a product with image src of 'test' or something else that is not a link or not reachable our db (sequelize) reruns the select statement as (i think) the request to the image (/product/test) failed (I didnt program it so that it resends the stmt to db).
This is a big error because it then overwrites the product array with a empty array as the SELECT statement checks WHERE id = 'test'.

I dont know why... Please help me out, Thanks.

Here's the code and the error:

**[Console Log]**

```
P--R--O--D--U--C--T: [
  product {
    dataValues: {
      id: 4,
      title: 'teset',
      price: 34234.45,
      imageUrl: 'etssetsetset',
      description: 'dfsdfsdfrtegdrdfg',
      createdAt: 2021-06-05T15:33:58.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-06-05T15:33:58.000Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 4,
      title: 'teset',
      price: 34234.45,
      imageUrl: 'etssetsetset',
      description: 'dfsdfsdfrtegdrdfg',
      createdAt: 2021-06-05T15:33:58.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-06-05T15:33:58.000Z
    },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions: {
      timestamps: true,
      validate: {},
      freezeTableName: false,
      underscored: false,
      paranoid: false,
      rejectOnEmpty: false,
      whereCollection: [Object],
      schema: null,
      schemaDelimiter: '',
      defaultScope: {},
      scopes: {},
      indexes: [],
      name: [Object],
      omitNull: false,
      sequelize: [Sequelize],
      hooks: {}
    },
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `price`, `imageUrl`, `description`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `products` AS `product` WHERE `product`.`id` = 'etssetsetset';
P--R--O--D--U--C--T: []
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at C:\Users\NULL\Desktop\05-deleting-products\controllers\shop.js:26:32
```

Here you see that it first is a product array with values but then after the image failed to load, the stmt reruns with WHERE id = 'est...' (image url that failed to load bc of no link)

**[EJS Template]**

```
        <main class="centered">
            <h1><%= product.title %></h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="<%= product.imageUrl %>" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <h2><%= product.price %></h2>
            <p><%= product.description %></p>
            <%- include('../includes/add-to-cart.ejs') %>
        </main>
```

Here you see that i even included a alt tag as a backup but it doesn't work it gets overwritten too somehow

**[Controller Code of that request handler]**

```
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    const prodId = req.params.productId;
    Product.findByPk(prodId)
        .then(product => {
            console.log('P--R--O--D--U--C--T:', product);

            res.render('shop/product-detail', {
            product: product,
            pageTitle: product.title,
            path: '/products'
        });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

So you see, i make one request to sequelize and it gets the product at first but after ejs template was sent and the image failed to load due no real url it rerunned the sequelize statement with WHERE id ='url of image' and so it couldnt find products anymore so product is empty array

So now my question is why does it rerun the statement and why doesn't it render the alt text instead of making new requests?

Thanks very much in advance

PS: In the network tab i get: Blocked - GET - localhost:3000/products/etsset... - img

Answer (score 0):

When `/products/4` is rendered, an product with ID `4` is rendered. This product exists.

On the rendered page you link `<img src="etssetsetset">`. You say that is 'no real URL' and 'no link' but that is not true. It's a perfectly valid link. It's relative to the current page, `/products/4` so it will load `/products/etssetsetset`.

When `/products/etssetsetset` is rendered, no product is returned. This causes errors.

Just because a URL doesn't point to an image doesn't mean your browser won't attempt to load it. It's a perfectly fine link, how is it supposed to know it doesn't point to an image, but rather a `text/html` page (one with errors / 404)? If `imageURL` was `/about` you'd *expect it* to *try and fail* to render your about-us page as an image, right? Same here.

You should check if the query in `getProduct` returns no results. If there are none, return a 404 and don't try to render the page because it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Thanks. Solved it by making a filter if image url is valid.